# Applying limit in listing large numbers of files in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a folder with millions of images stored in it. I want to get **10 random jpg** images from that folder.

I am trying below code to list the images and it gives a big list of all the images after so much time (5-6 minutes) where I can apply if condition to determine the jpg and can get 10 random records from the list.

```
fs.readdir(imageFolder, function (err, files) {
        console.log(files.length);
});
```

Is there any quick way to list only few images of required extension?

Comment: Don't put that many files in one directory.  Break them up into no more than a thousand per directory.  Then you can randomly select a directory and then randomly select a file in that directory without having to list so many files.

Comment: I got one old project having millions of images in one folder, I am not allowed to change the folder structure.

Comment: Then, you're out of luck.  It's a crummy design to have that many files in a folder.  It does not work well for what you're trying to do.  You could list all the filenames once in the background when the server starts and then put them in a database or some other data structure and select from there so you don't have to list them each time you need one.

Comment: @MohammadShahid and what about filenames? Are they random or there are some logic?

Comment: you can checkout [stream read directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757293/how-to-stream-read-directory-in-node-js) stack overflow question.

Comment: @Dyrk, they are random images.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution,

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;

child = exec('find '+imageFolder+' -name "*.jpg" | shuf -n 10', function (error, output, stderr) {

  console.log(output);

});
```