# NodeJS read huge directory file by file

Tags: node.js, fs

I have a directory composed of empty files and I want to iterate through each of their names. However I have nearly 20 million of these empty files and to load them all into memory with `fs.readdir` or `fs.readdirSync` would both take needlessly long and devour all my memory on the system.

What would be a way to go about this?

Ideally I would look for something that reads file by file in an async fashion with code that would ressemble the following:

`readdirfilebyfile((filename)=>{....})` so that at no point would I keep the entire list of files in memory.

The current solution I am using is dumping all the file names into a single file which I then read as a data stream. However, this is just running away from a problem that I should know how to solve without resorting to this.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757293/how-to-stream-read-directory-in-node-js There also is https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/t0ziBVsPRqw There are some indirect solutions at least in the second link. There is no direct solution purely within node.js I think. But the answer in the linked SO thread says it's no problem (and he tried), you just have to ensure not to start processing them all at once, just reading that big list seems to be fine. Okay - 600 MB of memory if I use his calculations as a basis for your scenario....

Comment: @Mörre I upvoted the question just now because OP didn't get a functional answer. The answer still wants to read all file names into memory. I want something that works by accessing an `n` file without reading the ones that came before it or after.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What action do you want to perform on those filenames?

Comment: That is why I included the 2nd link. Did you have a look at it? There is no "pure" node.js solution.

Comment: @robertklep Pass the names to an arbitrary function that will do things irrelevant to filesystem I/O

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I would probably use `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 node script.js` for this, with which you can easily limit the number of filenames being passed (as command line argument) to the Node script. However, that would only work if your arbitrary function is (relatively) pure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one? pv is pipe viewer, a rate limiter for bash pipes.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const tail = spawn('tail -f /tpm/filelist | pv -l -L 10 -q');
tail.stdout.on('data', fileName => {
  // parse filenames here
  console.log(fileName);
});
exec('ls > /tpm/filelist');
```