# How to efficiently read file names when there are > 1 million files in directory (in Bash)

Tags: bash, macos, shell, fs

I am running `find . -exec stat -f '%N,%a' {} +` in a directory with **> 1 million** files. It just hangs and uses CPU. I left it running for over 5 minutes and still no output. I don't want it to crash my computer.

What other ways are there to read the directory files in a way that doesn't load the whole thing into memory.

I can't change the directory structure, I need it to have these > 1 million files in a flat directory.

Comment: Check out this serverfault question: https://serverfault.com/questions/193319/a-better-unix-find-with-parallel-processing

Comment: Is there an naming convention that has been used?

Comment: There is a naming convention for some of them, but not all of them...

Comment: Btw, how do you know all files are loaded into memory? Did you check your memory usage to verify this?

Comment: I don't know, I just assumed that's what would happen. That seems to be happening with node's [`fs.readdir`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757293/how-to-stream-read-directory-in-node-js) as well.

Comment: Ah, it took `320490ms` (> 5 min) to load all the _top-level_ files into memory in node.

Comment: Can't reproduce (Linux, GNU find v4.7.0):  I just created a directory with 1 million files in it and ran your command.  It started returning results instantly.  Have you tried installing GNU `find` via homebrew to see if it works better?  Also, have you run `fsck` on your disk to verify that it's in good condition?

Comment: Did you mean `stat -c '%N,%a'` rather than `stat -f '%N,%a'`?