# How to stream directory to read file names in C

Tags: c, stream

So you [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204321/how-to-efficiently-read-file-names-when-there-are-1-million-files-in-directory) stream the directories in Node.js until a new version of libuv with streaming support is added.

Which makes me wonder, how you can implement directory entry list *stream* in C. I essentially just want to build a CSV with `<filename>,<timestamp>`, and with C it seems I might be able to stream a folder which has over 100 million files (external hard drive).

Comment: Do you want them as a literal stream or [would this thing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-readdir) be fine? I'm not sure what you mean by streaming as [Node streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) are a thing. Writing a recursive file finder in C can't be that hard, it's the sort of thing the `find` tool does.

Comment: I explicitly want to avoid loading the entire directory names into memory. So for 100mil files in a directory, that is a lot of bytes to load into memory. I want to stream them in batches or one at a time or something.

Comment: I get that. This doesn't take terabytes of memory or anything. You just fetch sequentially using C APIs like [`readdir`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir), then recurse into each directory you find. You only need enough memory to handle the maximum path depth, but that's generally fairly limited anyway. You'll want to add code to avoid following symlink loops, but otherwise it's really simple.