# What's the recommended way to deal with Range Errors

Tags: node.js

I encounter an error in my code that's caused by a too large output.

Consider this code:

**index.js:**

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const dirs = spawn('dir', { shell: true });

let fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path')

dirs.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    const wlist = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'wlist.txt'), 'utf-8')
    .split('\n')
    .filter((line) => line.trim() !== '')

    for (let word of wlist) {
        console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    }
});
```

For each item in wordlist, console log the output of a spawn command - good and all. However, what if the server has a million items that return from the "dir" command? well, this happens:

**Error:**

```
RangeError [ERR_CHILD_PROCESS_STDIO_MAXBUFFER]: stderr maxBuffer length exceeded
```

I couldn't just re-set the buffer limit as it will be heavy on the running host (i guess).

Conceptually, I think one may divide output to chunks somehow, and log them by parts - however this is a far fetched idea I don't know how to imply.

**Main question:**

What is the recommended way to handle this amount of data in the described scenario?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may answer your question
[how-to-stream-read-directory-in-node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757293/how-to-stream-read-directory-in-node-js)

`data` property will be too large for NodeJS to handle this. 
Stream will solve it - your current solution is pulling n directories at once.